# Numbers in char array printing as random characters

Tags: c

So I'm writing a somewhat simple C program that is supposed to take a string of characters separated by semicolons as input.  The program is then supposed to sort the strings by length and print them to the console.
Ex: `abc;12;def;1234`

The issue I'm having is that any numbers that are entered end up being printed as random symbols and I'm not sure why.  I'm taking in input in this function:

```
void get_strings(char** c)
{
    while (scanf("%[^;]s", c[numStrings]) != EOF)
    {
            getchar();
            numStrings += 1;
    }
}
```

Since scanf is looking for strings, if numbers are entered, are they stored as the 'character form' of those numbers, or should I be casting somehow?

Here's the rest of the code:

```
int numStrings = 0;

void sort_strings(char** c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numStrings; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numStrings - i; j++)
        {
            if (strlen(c[j]) > strlen(c[j + 1]))
            {
                char temp[1000];
                strcpy(c[j], temp);
                strcpy(c[j + 1], c[j]);
                strcpy(temp, c[j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

void show_strings(char** c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numStrings; i++)
    {
        if (printf("%s\n", c[i]) != EOF) break; 
    }
}

int main()
{
    char wordLen[100][1000];
    char* word2[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        word2[i] = wordLen[i];
    }

    char** words = word2;

    get_strings(words);
    sort_strings(words);
    show_strings(words);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you assign to `c` ? If so, how? [mcve]

Comment: @BLUEPIXY c is a pointer to a character pointer array in which every element points to an index in a 2d array (points to the first character in each word)

Comment: @XtenanetX Since your explanation has no meaning(It is impossible for us to verify whether it is doing it correctly or not) Please add the code of that part.

Comment: `strcpy(c[j], temp);` --> `strcpy(temp, c[j]);`

Comment: `if (printf("%s\n", c[i]) != EOF) break;` --> `printf("%s\n", c[i]);`

Comment: `j < numStrings - i;` --> `j < numStrings - i - 1;`

Comment: I already answered this question with the exact same example in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46880398/2d-array-output-and-sorting/46890870#46890870). SO Is *not* a site for people doing your homework and I'm sorry I answered it earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parsing code is incorrect:

```
void get_strings(char **c) {
    while (scanf("%[^;]s", c[numStrings]) != EOF) {
        getchar();
        numStrings += 1;
    }
}
```

- the `scanf()` format contains an extra `s` that does not match the input.
- the return value of `scanf()` should be compared to `1` to ensure successful conversion. Conversion failure produces `EOF` only at end of file, otherwise it produces `0` and the contents of `c[numStrings]` will be indeterminate.
- conversion stops at the first character `;`, this character stays in the input stream, but it is read by `getchar()`, yet if there is an empty field, the corresponding conversion would fail and the contents of the array would be indeterminate.
- you should not use a global variable for the number of strings read. You should instead return this number.

The sorting code is incorrect too:

- the inner loop runs one index too far: `j + 1` must be less than `numStrings` for all runs.
- the arguments to `strcpy` are passed in the wrong order.
- `strcpy` should not be used at all, you should just swap the pointers.

`show_strings()` always stops after the first line as `printf` will return the number of characters printed.

You can fix the reading loop this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int get_strings(char **c, int maxStrings) {
    int numStrings = 0;
    while (numStrings < maxStrings) {
        switch (scanf("%999[^;]", c[numStrings])) {
          case 1:
            getchar();
            numStrings += 1;
            break;
          case 0:
            if (getchar() == ';') {
                c[numStrings] = '\0';
                numStrings += 1;
            }
            break;
          case EOF:
            return numStrings;
        }
    }
}

void sort_strings(char **c, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < count - i - 1; j++) {
            if (strlen(c[j]) > strlen(c[j + 1])) {
                char *temp = c[j];
                c[j] = c[j + 1];
                c[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void show_strings(char **c, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", c[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char words[1000][100];
    char *wordPtrs[100];
    int numStrings;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        wordPtrs[i] = words[i];
    }

    numStrings = get_strings(wordPtrs, 100);
    sort_strings(wordPtrs, numStrings);
    show_strings(wordPtrs, numStrings);
    return 0;
}
```